# jQuery text match

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor tag with text and I want to check if the given var matches the string exactly.

This works, but I would like to use something other than contains, since it will match two elements if the contain the given string. I want it to match exactly.

Any ideas ?

```
function test(submenu){
$('a:contains("' + submenu + '")', 'ul.subMenu li').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `.filter()` function instead of the `:contains` filter to apply a custom filter to your selector result set.

In this case apply a custom filter to look for text with an exact match.  Something like:

```
$('a').filter( function (index) {
    return $(this).text() == submenu;
})
  .css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Comment: If boundary whitespace needs to be ignored just tweak as such: $.trim($(this).text()) == submenu

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
function test(submenu)
{
   if ($("ul.submenu li a").text() == submenu)
   { 
      // do whatever here 
   }
}
```

However, I'm not sure what you mean by, "This works, but I would like to use something other than contains, since it will match two elements if the contain the given string. I want it to match exactly."

Comment: You probably want to replace `=` with `==`. ;)

Comment: if submenu = 'News' then it would match a link with text 'News' and 'Testing News', therefore applying the css to both.

Comment: Corrected now, thanks jordan.  @gmcalab, this code and the above (and better code) by womp will do exact matching.