# jQuery :contains(), but to match an exact string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

As said in the title, I'd like to find something like `:contains()` but to match an exact string. In other words, it shouldn't be a partial match. For example in this case:

```
<div id="id">
   <p>John</p>
   <p>Johny</p>
</div>
```

`$("#id:contains('John')")` will match both `John` and `Johny`, while I'd like to match only `John`.

Thanks in advance.

<sub>**EDIT:** ES2015 one-liner solution, in case anyone looked for it:</sub>

```js
const nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('#id > *')].filter(node => node.textContent === 'John');

console.log(nodes);
```

```css
/* Output console formatting */
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; }
.as-console { height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="id">
  <p>John</p>
  <p>Johny</p>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery text match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883922/jquery-text-match)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `filter` for this:

```
$('#id').find('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'John';
});
```

---

Edit: Just as a performance note, if you happen to know more about the nature of what you're searching (e.g., that the nodes are immediate children of `#id`), it would be more efficient to use something like `.children()` instead of `.find('*')`.

---

Here's a jsfiddle of it, if you want to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Akuyq/

Answer (score 11):

jmar777's answer helped me through this issue, but in order to avoid searching everything I started with the :contains selector and filtered its results

```
var $results = $('#id p:contains("John")').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'John';
});
```

Heres an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Akuyq/34/

Comment: Just noticed this answer was posted here.  Just in case anyone else comes across this, it's actually *less* efficient to add the `:contains()` check.  Internally, `:contains()` has to loop over all the elements and perform a regex comparison for `"John"`.  We then have to loop over everything that passed that check with `filter()` on top of that.  Basically, worst-case complexity for this version is `O(2n)`, whereas every-case for mine is just `O(n)` (and yeah, I realize that sort of abuses Big O Notation, there...).

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a Regular Expression and searching off of that: [Regular expression field validation in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery)

Comment: It doesn't works really fine for me. Except that I also need to find solution how to search for string `John` between childrens of `#id`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is "select element by exact match" using pseudo function.

**Solution**
[Select element by exact match of its content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462522/4933464)