# Jquery simple search suggestion text highlight

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a simple jQuery word search based on an input of type text and highlighting text. How can I do this for multiple words? This code is only working for a single character.

**Html**

```
<input type="text"/>

<div>John Resig
    George Martin
    Malcom John Sinclair
    J. Ohn 
    Sample text
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
span {    
    background : red 
}
```

**JS**

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
     var mysearchword = $("input:text").val();    
     var word = mysearchword;
     $( "div:contains('"+word+"')" ).html(function(i,html) {
         var re = new RegExp(word,"g");
         return html.replace(re,'<span>'+word+'</span>')
     });
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/qrfavop2/10/)

Comment: Is this answer of any help to you?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript

Comment: This tutorial also looks helpful: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/

Comment: Try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571117/jquery-something-like-contains-but-to-match-exactly-phrase

Comment: Take advantage of what HTML5 offers you, and use `<mark>` to highlight your results, instead of `<span>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a predefined set of elements to target then

```js
var $para = $('.para')
$("input").keyup(function() {
  $para.find('span.highlight').contents().unwrap();
  var mysearchword = this.value.trim();
  if (mysearchword) {
    var re = new RegExp('(' + mysearchword.trim().split(/\s+/).join('|') + ')', "gi");
    $para.html(function(i, html) {
      return html.replace(re, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>')
    });
  }
});
```

```css
span.highlight {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div class="para">John Resig George Martin Malcom John Sinclair J. Ohn Sample text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. this is working fine. but <span class="highlight"></span> tags displaying when Iam deleting input text what I have typed.

Comment: @user3927335 can you give a case to recreate the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hnvzrcb3/3/

Comment: Better to simply use `var mysearchword = this.value;` instead of `var mysearchword = $("input:text").val();` that might select values from other `input` elements as well.

Comment: for Eg: when adding 'John Re' working fine. if you delete entered text with backspace then the content displaying <span> tags

Comment: @user3927335 see the update... the issue was when there is no search text

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit, and able to achieve what you need. I am not sure of the performance though.

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="inputText" />
<div id="sampleText">
   John Resig George Martin Malcom John Sinclair J. Ohn Sample text
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("input").keyup(function () {

   var mysearchword = $(this).val();
   var word = mysearchword;
   var textInDiv = $("#sampleText").text();
   if (textInDiv.indexOf(word) > 0) {
      var re = new RegExp(word, "g");
      $("#sampleText").html(textInDiv.replace(re, '<span>' + word +'</span>'));
   };
});
```