# jquery contains selector not working for specific innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, innerhtml, contains

I'm displaying a list of checkboxes using this code :

```
{% for keyword in keywords %}
    <div class="col m4 s12">
        <p class="range-field">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{loop.index}}" name="{{keyword.title}}" class="filled-in"/>
            <label for="{{loop.index}}">{{keyword.title}}</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100"/>
        </p>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

After sumbitting the form the server gets the list of selected checkboxes and sends them back so that I can check them back

```
{% for keyword in selected_keywords %}
    <script>
        $("label:contains('{{keyword.keyword}}')").prev().attr('checked',true);
    </script
{% endfor %}
```

I'm using contains as selector but it doesn't work for innerHTML. For example if I have java and javascript and i only check java after submitting javascript is also checked. I searched for other related problems and most of them seem to use contains which does not work for specific innerHTML.

Comment: You are using something else ? What framework makes echo for {{   }} ? Don't forget  innerHTML is literal or simple string type not object !

Comment: I'm using Flask. the data is a json array each element is a dict that has 2 keys : keyword and weight. The problem I'm having is in keyword because contains checks both of java and javascript when i only check java

Comment: You're using `:contains` which does essentially `text().indexOf(keyword) >= 0` - so "java" will be found in "javascript".  You need to use something that generates `text() == keyword` - there's duplicates in SO for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery :contains(), but to match an exact string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571117/jquery-contains-but-to-match-an-exact-string)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3Acontains+match

Comment: This is probably a better solution though - as it creates a new pseudo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content/18462522#18462522

Comment: @freedomn-m it works now thanks